# Question on probability of winning the game of die

Tags: probability

Two brothers $X$ and $Y$ play a game with a fair $n$-sided die whose faces are numbered $1, 2, 3, …, n$. In this game, $X$ is assigned a value $x$ and $Y$ is assigned a value $y$, both also in the range $1, 2, 3,…, n$. $X$ and $Y$ take turns rolling the die; $X$ goes first.

If $X$ rolls a number less than or equal to $x$, the game ends and he wins. If $Y$ rolls a number less than or equal to $y$, the game ends and he wins. The game continues until one player wins.

1. If $n = 6$, find all possible values of $x$ and $y$ which make the game fair, that is both have equal chances of winning.
2. If $n = 101$, show that no values of $x$ and $y$ will make the game fair.

For the second part, it seems that there's no such possible $x,y$. Can we say that if the probability is $x/n$, then, the answer would be $(1-\text {probability})^\text {number of attempts where he didn't win} \times$(x/n)?

No idea about the second part.

Comment: The answer to what?  You seem to be calculating a probability, but neither question asks for that.  Have you done the first part?

Comment: @saulspatz By probability I meant the possibility. It may not be a question on probability. And no, I am not done with the first part as well

Comment: It's certainly a question on probability, in part.  To say it's a fair game is to say that the probability that X wins is equal to the probability that Y wins.  Since there are no ties, each probability is $1/2.$  What is the probability that X wins on the first round?  What about Y?

Comment: This is problem #1 from the [Mathcamp Qualifying Quiz](http://www.mathcamp.org/prospectiveapplicants/quiz/index.php). Asking questions about it before the deadline of March 15th violates the [MSE contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy).